# Cannot find the Trigger target due to inserted code

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I'm running into this error "Cannot find the Trigger target 'connectStatus'.  (The target must appear before any Setters, Triggers, or Conditions that use it.)" and I don't know why. The target is already defined prior to the DataTrigger which is strange.

```
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type src:ScannedStimulatorItem}">
        <src:ScannedItem/>
        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Connected}" 
                         Value="true">
                <Setter TargetName="AutomationConnectStatus" 
                        Property="AutomationProperties.ItemStatus" 
                        Value="ConnectionState:true"/>
                <Setter TargetName="ConnectStatus" //Error here
                        Property="Fill" 
                        Value="{StaticResource OnBrush}" /> 
            </DataTrigger>
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>
```

ScannedItem is a big block of code that put into another xaml file. I don't get the error prior to this refactor. Inside this ScannedItem UserControl is

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
     // Row and Column definitions
     // Lots of xaml code
    <TextBlock x:Name="AutomationConnectStatus"
               AutomationProperties.AutomationId="{Binding Serial, StringFormat=CONNECT_\{0\}ConnectionStatus_Icon}"
               AutomationProperties.ItemStatus="ConnectionState:false">
        <InlineUIContainer>
            <Ellipse x:Name="ConnectStatus"
                     Width="12" 
                     Height="12" 
                     Fill="{StaticResource OffBrush}" 
            />
        </InlineUIContainer>
    </TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

Another odd observation: I don't get this error with AutomationConnectStatus at all (I removed the connectStatus trigger to check). Also, I don't think InlineUIContainer is the problem because I have other triggers that have this issue but they aren't defined within an InlineUIContainer.

Comment: Sorry about that. I was trying different things earlier and this inconsistency was the result; however this wasn't the cause of the issue. I've edited my post to correct the typo.

Comment: I'm not so sure you can insert into a DataTemplate like that. When I cut and paste the xaml directly in I don't get the error.

Comment: Thank you Jeff. If anyone knows can you tell me why this happens? I would have assumed that inserting code just copies over the contents of ScannedItem into the DataTemplate. Also, is there a standard name for this concept of inserting xaml into another xaml file?